# How to rotate a UITextView without it resizing?

Tags: ios, uitextview

I am trying to rotate a UITextView in my VC. When I try to rotate it the UITextView resizes its?

Here is my code.

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        self.title = @"Signature View";

        [self.signatureView setLineWidth:2.0];
        self.signatureView.foregroundLineColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.204 green:0.596 blue:0.859 alpha:1.000];

         NSLog(@"contentsize: %.0f, %.0f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height); <-- this is (contentsize: 320, 568)

        self.howToTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width); 

        [self.howToTextView setNeedsDisplay]; <-- to make it redraw 

        [self.howToTextView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90* M_PI/180)];

        NSLog(@"contentsize: %.0f, %.0f", self.howToTextView.contentSize.width, self.howToTextView.contentSize.height); <--- turns out to be (contentsize: 103, 138)same as on storyboard design

    }
```

UPDATE(With this code the uitextview is in place and the frame is right, but not the text won't resize to fill up the uitextviews new frame size. Its stuck down in the bottom corner?):

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

        self.title = @"Signature View";

        [self.signatureView setLineWidth:2.0];
        self.signatureView.foregroundLineColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.204 green:0.596 blue:0.859 alpha:1.000];

         NSLog(@"contentsize: %.0f, %.0f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

        self.howToTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        self.howToTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.howToTextView.text = @"this is a good day. i am going to make millions today. Smile while on the phone as it is the best way to increase your business. I hope that you like this app as we have work really hard on it. Please sign your name or decline but if you decline then you understand you lose all  coverage.";

        [self.view addSubview:self.howToTextView];


        [self.howToTextView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90* M_PI/180)];
        self.howToTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 80, self.view.frame.size.height);
        [self.howToTextView setNeedsDisplay];

        NSLog(@"contentsize: %.0f, %.0f", self.howToTextView.contentSize.width, self.howToTextView.contentSize.height);

    }
```

UPDATE 2: Sticking the textview inside a UIView makes the content size right, but now with this code the uitextview/uiview are in the top right corner of the app, even though I set them both to be 0,0 for x,y? Not sure why that is?

```
        self.howToTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        [self.howToTextView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height-20, 110)];
        self.howToTextView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.howToTextView.text = @"this is a good day. i am going to make millions today. Smile while on the phone as it is the best way to increase your business. I hope that you like this app as we have work really hard on it. Please sign your name or decline but if you decline then you understand you lose all  coverage.";

        UIView *myRotateView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        [myRotateView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.height, 120)];
        [myRotateView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
        [myRotateView addSubview:self.howToTextView];

        myRotateView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-90* M_PI/180);
        [[self view] addSubview:myRotateView];
```

Comment: If you're using storyboards, it's likely that your content size is being modified even without the transform. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes I removed from the storyboard and creating it manually now. I have it in the right shape and size, but NOW the text is only taking up about .10 of UITextView. Its like the outer edges of the UITextView have changed correctly but the inner content and text doesn't realize it. Updating code above.

Answer (score 0):

After two days of struggling, I found a workaround:

1. Create a UIView.
2. Add your UITextView as a sub view to it.
3. Get the proper size of UITextView, using sizeThatFits().
4. Set UITextView frame.
5. Set UIView frame with 0 heigh and 0 width (it's important!).
6. Rotate your UIView.

Now if you want to change font size do it like this:

```
myTextView.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(size)
let maxsize = CGSizeMake(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT)
let frame = myTextView.sizeThatFits(maxsize)
myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.width, frame.height)
```

At end rotate the UIView again.